# Builders on abstract classes cannot be @Jacksonized (the builder would never be used)

Tags: java, jboss, jackson, wildfly, lombok

I have two classes **OAuth2Token** and **CachedOAuth2Token** that extends a class called **AbstractOAuth2Token**.

**AbstractOAuth2Token.java**

```
@SuperBuilder
@Jacksonized
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OAuth2Token.class),
})
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public abstract class AbstractOAuth2Token {
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String tokenType;
}
```

**OAuth2Token.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@JsonTypeName("OAuth2Token")
@Jacksonized
public class OAuth2Token extends AbstractOAuth2Token {
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private int expiresIn;
}
```

**CachedOAuth2Token.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class CachedOAuth2Token extends AbstractOAuth2Token {
    private LocalDateTime expirationDate;
}
```

Unfortunately my Maven project doesn't build because `AbstractOAuth2Token.java: Builders on abstract classes cannot be @Jacksonized (the builder would never be used).`

Even if the code works as expected if the **AbstractOAuth2Token** isn't abstract, then I'm able to create an instance of it using the builder which indeed isn't what I want. Its constructor is *protected*, so no problem there.

The idea is that I want **AbstractOAuth2Token** to be abstract without losing any fuctionality in the children. I'm a fan of Lombok, so I want to be able to use the autogenerated builders but together with Jackson.

It's a Wildfly 11 project with Lombok 1.18.16

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't add `@Jacksonized` to your `abstract` base class. Non-`@Jacksonized` `@SuperBuilder`s are compatible with `@Jacksonized` `@SuperBuilder`s. As Jackson will never use `AbstractOAuth2Token`'s builder directly, there is no need to configure it for Jackson explicitly.

Comment: I'll try this after I finish my current task and let you know about the outcome

Comment: I tested it now and it works! Thanks for the help :)